# update record in data base table in php

Tags: php

I am trying to update record in table by getting an id from another .php file..But it can't update .Please help. Here is my code.

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$member_id = $_GET['id']; 
echo ("You are going to edit/update record of employee with id #");echo $member_id;

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $firstname =$_REQUEST['firstname'];
    $lastname =$_REQUEST['lastname'];
    $phone =$_REQUEST['phone'];    
    $insert = "update emp set SET firstname ={'$firstname'}, lastname = {'$lastname'} phone = {'$phone'} WHERE id = {'$member_id'}";
    mysql_query($insert);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you have two `SET` and because of that query was failing and also you forgot `,` before `phone = {`

```
$insert = "update emp set SET firstname ={'$firstname'}, lastname = {'$lastname'} phone = {'$phone'} WHERE id = {'$member_id'}";
```

should be

```
$insert = "update emp SET firstname ={'$firstname'}, lastname = {'$lastname'}, phone = {'$phone'} WHERE id = {'$member_id'}";
```

**EDIT**

write this to check the error

```
mysql_query($insert) OR die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply.i have done it.But it again have the same problem.I cant update my data.

Comment: @user2289063 Yeah you forgot `,` before `phone = {`. I have included this in my answer.

Comment: Thanks it works now..and also colons should b outside the curly brackets..In string fields.